# How can I Reapeat TextBox in every report page?

Tags: c#, sql-server, reporting-services, rdlc

I have a client report (rdlc) and want to repeat some textboxes in every pages. I can't put these textboxes in header. I bind data to these textboxes, so I can't put these at header.

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i assume that the data you are using is same for every page so why don't you pass this data as report parameter this way you will be able to display it in the header. In hte header you can display report parameters
Best Regards,
Iordan

Comment: I don't want use parameter. Is there any solution?

Comment: it depends on what actually want to achieve lets say you have report that Shows list of something the you can use datatable in you report put these fields in the header of the datatable. After that you just need to set the property "RepeatOnNewPage" of the datatable header to true

Answer (score 3):

If you use a table and place a rectangle into the table header, you can freely place text boexs within that rectangle and you can set the table header to repeat on each page. Either with that or grouping/group headers, you should be able to pretty much handle every situation in your data.

RDLC, btw, is the extension for Report Viewer Control reports that have little in common with Reporting Services reports, at least in Visual Studio 2008 and SQL Server 2008.